# Are compound selectors possible for jQuery in IE7?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

Quite the issue I have here as this is not a problem on IE8+ and other updated browsers. Here's the line of code I'm using in order to access the respective elements:

```
$('.contactInfo input[type="text"], .companyInfo input[type="text"]').each(function () {...});
```

What I'm doing in the line above is getting each text box from each div with the classes .contactInfo and .companyInfo. This works perfectly in everything except IE7. I'm starting to believe that this isn't possible for 7 but if so, I'd love know how it's done. It's not urgent as I've come up with a workaround but a solution for this would be much more efficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 99.99% of the reason to use jQuery is to eliminate user agent considerations. I would say that if compound selectors are NOT possible with jQuery in IE7, it is time to find a new cross-browser shimming library.

Comment: jQuery 1.9 dropped support for IE7, no? Try the 1.8.x branch if you're using anything newer.

Comment: If this didn't work then it would be a bug in [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which sounds unlikely. Are you triple sure?

Comment: @Mark That's jQuery 2.0, 1.9 still supports the Explorers: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

Comment: Pardon me for not saying, but I'm using this line as part of my validation markup in order to verify the contents of a few text boxes. In IE7, it completely ignores that particular line and therefore disregards all of my validation. It works perfectly in IE8+ and everything else.

Comment: I think JCG has it right -- jQuery is shimming support for what doesn't exists (that's why you're using it!). But, like any shim, there are possible limitations. I suspect you'll have to split the two groups of inputs into two each loops, or find a more simplistic selector to grab them all in one go.

Comment: @Chris I agree! I marked his statement as an answer because that was the workaround I had thought of, to break it in two and do my validation that way. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: Ah. I think I was confused because of all the stuff they removed. I had a lot of compatibility issues with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long answer to your question is that using JQuery in IE7, it is possible to use compound selectors, but with a caveat.

IE7 does not support querySelectorAll(), so with larger numbers of selectors, or simply selectors who's inner HTML takes a long time to process, the "each" request will time out.

It's not JQuery, it's the browser, and to fix this, you either need to separate the loops, or use more qualified selectors.

for reference: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9921

Comment: I see! I figured I'd have to make two separate loops because I tried a ton of different ways to make it work on one line to no avail. Thanks for making me see that that's how I should be doing it anyway!

Comment: Just a caveat, `querySelectorAll()` (and `querySelector()`) is part of the *DOM*, not jQuery. This is why Sizzle is mentioned, as it is the fallback when those DOM methods are not available (and to wit, by degrees slower than the native methods). I also see that both of those are marked invalid, so I'm not sure how much of an answer this represents.